# Javascript: Editing the Value of a Form Field?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is my html:

```
<div class="myFormField">
     <input type="text" class="myFormField city" value="" name="city" id="city">
</div>
```

I'm trying the to set the following but it's not working, it's returning undefined when I test with alerts:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myFormField city").value = "New York";
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myFormField city")[0].value = "New York";
```

Please take a look at the documentation for [**`getElementsByClassName`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName):

> "Returns a set of elements which have all the given class names."

`getElementsByClassName` returns a **set** of elements, so you need to access a specific element in that set to give it a value - first element of the set being `[0]`, second is `[1]` etc.

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/GVgJP/)

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myFormField city")
```

will return array of elements

so use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myFormField city")[0].value
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the `document.getElementsByClassName` gets the array of elements with classname given . So your code should be,

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myFormField city")[0].value = "New York"
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have ID

`document.getElementById("city").value = "New York";`